# Django-Socialauth or django-social-auth, which one is the best?

Tags: django, facebook, openid, django-socialauth, socialauth

I am looking for a Django application to implement Facebook-connect, and I have found 2 options that look pretty stable:

- https://github.com/agiliq/Django-Socialauth/
- https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth

They seem to be forks of each other, but they are in fact different applications. Has anybody tried both of them? If so, which one would you recommend me?

Thanks!

Comment: I finally opted for https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth and I am happy with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've had the best experience with django-social-auth. It has the best docs, no weird templates, code looks clean, and issues are solved very quick. It's also very easy to combine with a javascript openid plugin like http://jvance.com/pages/jQueryOpenIdPlugin.xhtml.

Comment: Thanks, I am also happy with django-social-auth :)

Answer (score 9):

I tried django-socialregistration, Django-Socialauth, django-social-auth, and django-allauth, and wrote a [review](https://hackerluddite.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/review-of-4-django-social-auth-apps/) of them.

django-allauth is the only one that worked out of the box for me.  And it's the only one that supports both username/password registration as well as social auth.